# Upload multiple document files in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement of uploading the multiple documents with the help of file upload control. The same thing I had done for the Image type. It is working perfectly since it takes only 1 image file. But the multiple file upload is not working. What's the flaw in my code How can I do it?

```
  Html Code:
  ----------
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Block", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
       <div class="col-lg-4" id="FileUp">
           <label>Upload File</label>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DocumentFilesPath, new { @name="fileUpload", @id="fileUpload", @type = "file",  @multiple="multiple", @class="form-control dropDownLabel", @onchange="fileTypeCheck()" } )
       </div>

   // What should I specify the type for DocumentFilesPath in @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DocumentFilesPath) in my strongly typed model? 

       <div class="col-lg-8>                                 
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveBlock" onclick="checkSubmit()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>Save
              </button>
       </div>
    }

  My Controller Action:
  ---------------------

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BlockViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.BlockID == 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["imgUpload"] as HttpPostedFileBase;    // I am able to get the single file here
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/uploads/") + file.FileName);

                model.ImageFilepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/uploads/") + file.FileName;
            }

            IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> docFiles = Request.Files["fileUpload"] as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>;   // But here docFiles is null
            //IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> docFiles = fileUpload as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>;
            if (docFiles != null)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase docFile in docFiles)
                {
                    if (docFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        docFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Files/") + docFile.FileName);

                        model.DocumentFilesPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Files/") + docFile.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Request.Files["imgUpload"]`? Just add a parameter `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> documentFilesPath` to the method (and remove the pointless `new { @name="fileUpload" }` in your view which does nothing)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I had tried in that way too. I got the result as null

Comment: Then that suggests an issue with your plugin. What is it and how is it configured? And what is `fileTypeCheck()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, it contains enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am new to MVC. Which plugin you are talking about?

Comment: You code suggests you have some scripts. What are they?

Comment: Note also if you wanting to bind the files to your model, then the property needs to be `public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> DocumentFilesPath { get; set; }`

Comment: @Stephen : does the answer satisfy his problem ?

Comment: @REDEVI_, What answer?

Comment: @Stephen: the one I ve posted ...

Comment: @REDEVI_, You dot need to have _multiple file inputs all with the same name_ - you can have just one marked with the `multiple="multiple"` attribute (as OP is doing)

Comment: @stephen : thanks , I was not aware of that ..

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. It works. I added a parameter IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> DocumentFilesPath

Comment: @PSriharsha have a look at this link, it might help you understand better regarding file uploads. http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link for multiple file uploads ,,
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Basic Idea   is We can simply have
multiple file inputs all with the same name.

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

      <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

      <input type="submit"  />
    </form>
```

and in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
  foreach (var file in files) {
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
      file.SaveAs(path);
    }
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```